# how can I connect my ec2 instance to a registered domain?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

Hi I'm trying to make a test server to get Facebook authentication working.

am using python flask, current app itself is a copy of [this oauth sample](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-oauth-example). nothing else.

so, I have set up everything I could think of:

- an ACM to get https working,
- a Load balancer(classic) - have set up cert from ACM i made above and the instance I want to connect to.
- domain address registered in route 53, set up an alias target(the ELB)
- etc.

and after setting this up I went into my ec2 instance using putty, set up an virtual env. and ran the app using the venv. aaaaand the app itself is working fine, except the ELB health check can't pick it up, nor when I try to access by typing in the domain address.

it only works when typing in EC2 instance's public IP. and now I'm stuck here, now knowing how to 'integrate' the instance to my registered domain...

the instance status in the load balance's instance tab shows `OutOfService`

^ EDIT: the instance tab works, it was due to PORT number. but domain still doesnt responds...

is there anything else I could check to do this? any help is greatly appreciated.... been stuck with this for over a month now :(

EDIT: currently the ELB gets health checks from ec2 instances properly. but I get infinite loading when I try to access by typing in domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to troubleshoot on here- but I would bet that you need to setup the security group so that the load balancer can hit the correct port on your EC2 instance (That is the most common cause of this)

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/fh5MAI2) is my current inbound for my security. outbound is set as `all traffic`

Comment: does my flask hosted port need to match as well? it's on default value(5000)

Comment: Yes, you need to have an inbound rule on the EC2 instance for the port that Flask listens to, and an outbound rule on the ELB for that port as well.

Comment: Also, from your description, you aren't running a server on 80 or 443 on your instance, so should probably not have all those ports open.

Comment: ah, thank you. resetting ports did the trick. but still... kinda weird, writing domain addr works at one point, and some other case it doesnt... :/

Comment: You probably had your local machine setup to access the instance so that you could do work, just forgot the ELB had to be able to talk to it as well.

Comment: talk to it? according to the health check it's working fine.... I can see the log loading... or is this not what you're saying?